# style android:dropDownListViewStyle not working for samsung devices

Tags: android, themes

Applying style for actionOverflow menu item, it is working for motorola-xoom  tablet(Android 4.1.2), but it is not working for samsung devices(tab+phone).

Here is my code in **style.xml**

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
 <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can I know samsung devices tab+phone versions....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot item for support without android:?

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it helps to others:

from theme:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
 <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

attr dropDownListViewStyle only applies if you are using it in your spinner as dropdown item : android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item like that

```
mySpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
```

as you can see in android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item :

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

it applies spinnerDropDownItemStyle style defined in your theme, so if you NOT are using android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item in your spinner, you are using your own layout overriding spinnerDropDownItemStyle style attribute has no effect on your custom layout, so you should change your background color in your layout.